# Should I place a shower on an inaccessible wall?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower

I am planning a layout for a bathroom remodel. The best place to put the shower would be on a wall that is only accessible from the front (i.e. doesn't back onto a closet or another room). My contractor advised me against this because any repairs down the line would require removing the finish surface and retiling. The alternative layout which places the shower on an accessible wall is definitely not as desirable to me.

What would people advise in this situation? How common is it to have a shower valve etc only accessible from the front? How likely is this to cause problems?

Comment: Diagram and/or pictures would help.

Comment: go for the industrial look with surface mounted pipes

Comment: If pipes are inside the wall, then I think Dirty Harry said it best.  Do you feel lucky.

Comment: Standard shower valve installs are typically "accesible" only for the purpose of changing a cartridge/washers. Replacement of the valve body itself, or its connections with the supply piping mostly requires one to demolish and rebuild the tile/finish and its backing structure. There might be special oversize trim plates or overlay panels that could overcome that problem.

Comment: This is opinion based and, therefore, explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You _can_ put the shower on the exterior wall if you want - it's your house. Only _you_ can decide if the trade offs of doing so make this the "best" place for it.

Comment: A problem with this question, further to @FreeMan's comment, is that a huge portion of all showers cannot be repaired without breaking tile walls.  It's so common as to be "normal".  And yet, it's a terrible idea and there is no harm in you, in your own house, saying, "Wait.  Maintenance!" and thinking ahead.   So, either do what your contractor says, or do what I say in my answer, or don't, but it's your choice whether to prioritize maintenance and long term cost over other things.  It is sadly VERY common to install shower parts inside tiled exterior walls.

Comment: Building codes in some places, such as Ontario, forbid water feeds in outside walls.

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly urge following the contractor's recommendation.

If the shower is on an exterior wall:

- The plumber could have to remove a lot of tile to find the source of the leak.
- It could be difficult, expensive, or even impossible to find matching replacement tile, meaning there's a chance you could have to retile the whole shower.
- If the cement board behind the tile isn't patched correctly, it can provide a new point for intrusion of water from the shower.
- Turning off water to a shower generally requires turning it off to the entire house, and it'll have to be off for longer because it'll take the plumber longer to find and fix the leak.
- The entire repair could take days or longer, depending on the contractor's schedule and how much tile has to be redone.
- If your area experiences hard freezes, plumbing in an exterior wall is more likely to burst than in an interior wall.

Meanwhile, if the shower were on an interior wall:

- A plumber could cut out the drywall and fix most leaks in about an hour.
- You can resume using the shower immediately, without waiting on wall repair.
- Patching and painting the drywall is quick and inexpensive.

Even if a leak isn't terribly likely to occur, putting the shower on an exterior wall increases the chance (if you have freezes), and the time and cost to repair it is an order of magnitude greater. IMO it's not worth the risk unless the bathroom would be truly dysfunctional otherwise.

Comment: Great answer, good supporting reasoning too. Check out the [tour] for more about writing great answers, but you're off to a great start!

Answer (score 5):

You can have your cake and eat it.  An in-wall shower system has all the pitfalls noted above and also tends to be very expensive.  Instead, put the shower where you want and install a [shower panel](https://www.build.com/shower-systems/c108789?F19214=showerpanel&term=shower%20panel).  There is almost nothing inside the wall, just the supply pipes.  You get a rain head, hand shower, body heads, and usually more gimmicks all for the price of a typical shower valve alone.  And it comes as one piece and is easy to install, repair, and replace as everything is surface mounted, and connected to your house plumbing through a pair of hoses like a laundry machine.  IMO these things also look nice.  The bang for the buck is about 3 times that of an in-wall system, and that's on day 1.  Each time something goes wrong and you don't need a plumber or tiler to fix it, it keeps paying back.